# Change to uppercase all tables data

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have 190 layers in shape file with attribute filled in lower case. I want to change data of all tables in uppercase using Qgis.

I am able do to do it one by one using upper in expression.

How to do for all layers in one go?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use pyqgis to loop over all the field names to change their case to uppercase.

The following snippet can be used to change all field names in one shapefile into uppercase

```
uri = r"F:\Ahmad\Test\PT\Cities.shp"
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri, "cities", "ogr")
for field in vlayer.fields():
    name = field.name()
    with edit(vlayer):
        idx = vlayer.fields().indexFromName(name)
        vlayer.renameAttribute(idx, name.upper())

del vlayer
```

Before:

[image]

After running the code:

[image]

The above code was used inside QGIS 3.4.5 with pyqgis 3. If you want to loop over the 190 shapefile, you need to use [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).